# How do I select DOM created li's in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website where the user is able to create new LI items from an userinput like so:

```
function addNav(event, nav) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const navDiv = document.createElement("div");
    navDiv.classList.add("nav-div");
    const newNav = document.createElement('li');
    newNav.innerText = navInput.value;
    newNav.classList.add("nav-item");
    navDiv.appendChild(newNav);
    navlist.appendChild(navDiv);
    const upBtn = document.createElement("button");
    upBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>';
    upBtn.classList.add("up-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(upBtn);
    const downBtn = document.createElement("button");
    downBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>';
    downBtn.classList.add("down-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(downBtn);
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
    deleteBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>';
    deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    //savenav
    saveNavs(navInput.value);
    navInput.value = "";
```

These navs then save to local storage and every time site is loaded it creates the li items from an array stored in localstorage. However I want to create javascript/Jquery connected to the DOM created LI's but after days of research I can't find the answer. So my question is:
How do I select my DOM created Li's? (there's just a ul in the html file).

@mutedoriginal I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

var kokDiv = document.getElementById('nav-id').value;
console.log(kokDiv);

```
function addNav(event, nav) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const navDiv = document.createElement("div");
    navDiv.classList.add("nav-div");
    const newNav = document.createElement('li');
    newNav.innerText = navInput.value;
    newNav.classList.add("nav-item");
    navDiv.appendChild(newNav);
    navlist.appendChild(navDiv);
    const upBtn = document.createElement("button");
    upBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>';
    upBtn.classList.add("up-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(upBtn);
    const downBtn = document.createElement("button");
    downBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>';
    downBtn.classList.add("down-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(downBtn);
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
    deleteBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>';
    deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-button");
    navDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    newNav.setAttribute('id', 'nav-id');
    document.body.appendChild(navDiv);
    navlist.appendChild(newNav);
    //savenav
    saveNavs(navInput.value);
    navInput.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just add an ID to it using the .setAttribute() method

```js
var navDiv = document.createElement("div");
navDiv.setAttribute('id', 'nav-id');
navDiv.setAttribute('class', 'nav-class');
document.body.appendChild(navDiv);
document.getElementById('nav-id').innerHTML = 'Wow! You just changed the innerHTML of navDiv by assigning a ID to it using .setAttribute!!';
```

EDIT: made updated code that resolves basis for creating li from user input in simple html and javascript.

```js
function create() {
var makeLi = document.getElementById('inp').value;
var maker = document.createElement("li");
maker.innerHTML = makeLi;
document.getElementById('li holder').appendChild(maker); 
}
```

```html
Enter Element to become li:<input id="inp" value=""/><br>
<button onclick="create()">Submit</button>
<ul id="li holder"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer <3 I think we're onto something here however I'm not quite sure how to inegrate it. I tried like this:                         navDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    navDiv.setAttribute('id', 'nav-id');
    navDiv.setAttribute('class', 'nav-class');
    document.body.appendChild(navDiv);
    //savenav
    saveNavs(navInput.value);
    navInput.value = "";  (at the end of the addNav function) And then tried to console log it out: var stackAnswer = document.getElementById('nav-id');
console.log(stackAnswer); But just get answer : null

Comment: can you perhaps add it in a snippets or code block, please. It's a bit difficult for me to read it without the line breaks. :)

Comment: I just added a new example that might help you of a simpler way to create the elements with javascript. the HTML elements could be added into javascript as well for the entirety of it to be in js

Comment: @mutedorigial I don't know how to do that sorry I'm really new. Im trying to implement it now. Should I add it in my excisting create form?

Comment: I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: I just posted a question below where I formatted code